# Search function SQL in json array

Tags: php, sql, json

Hi everyone (hope the title is right, my english is rusted sometimes)

I did a search function, it work for my "code" infos, my company names, but i need to search for email, that are in a json entry, i did it like this :

```
    $sql = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ' . $this->table . ' AS s 
            WHERE ((s.code LIKE :q)
            OR (s.company_name LIKE :q)
            OR (JSON_EXTRACT(s.contacts, "$.email") LIKE :q))';
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Well, can you share example data of the JSON? One row should be sufficient, you can mask the real values, it's the structure that matters.

Comment: sure, [{"lastname":"Bonnot","firstname":"Jean","email":"justinbridou@live.fr","phone1":"0675421357"}]

Comment: I think it's failing because your JSON is in an array and not at the "top" level which `$.email` looks for

Comment: ok so my email is in the 2nd level, how do i do? maybe i should do a foreach of my "s.contacts" ?

Comment: Seems like `contacts` really ought to be another table. Would save you a lot of headaches like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i used this answer :

```
OR (JSON_EXTRACT(s.contacts, "$**.email") LIKE :q))';
```

Like @dazed-and-confused pointed my email wasn't at the top level, so i used ** to go to the 2nd level, and it work.

Comment: The only thing with this solution is that if the JSON string contains multiple arrays, this method will get all of them that match, not just one.

Comment: can't think of another way to do it, any suggestion?

Comment: `OR (JSON_EXTRACT(s.contacts, "$[0].email") LIKE :q))';`